# How can I tell the code is running on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

When I run google app engine locally, `sys.platform` reports `linux3`. It can mean I am running on a linux platform too.

What is the definitive way to tell my code is running in a google app engine environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to check if the  `APPENGINE_RUNTIME` environment variable is set

In python would be

```
import os
if 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME' in os.environ.keys():
    # working in appengine environment
```

This is a special appengine environment variable that is not set for regular programs.

If you are interested in other environment variables, here is the list

```
INSTANCE_ID 7ae067a39bdd37e8ab1cf40c711a6dbca84d
wsgi.url_scheme http
wsgi.multiprocess True
wsgi.version (1, 0)
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
REMOTE_ADDR 127.0.0.1
HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY ZZ
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
QUERY_STRING 
wsgi.run_once False
DATACENTER us1
REQUEST_METHOD GET
SERVER_SOFTWARE Development/2.0
HTTPS off
wsgi.multithread True
SCRIPT_NAME 
HTTP_ACCEPT */*
APPLICATION_ID dev~teledap-gae
SERVER_NAME localhost
USER_EMAIL 
REQUEST_LOG_ID 5e2e9ae098c4612cfdb1feebacea8dc5cb7e9e989355edfffcb4a30dbca2ecffa69b
wsgi.errors <google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice._LogsStreamBuffer object at 0x7fd47f9308d0>
PATH_INFO /
DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME localhost:8080
USER_NICKNAME 
APPENGINE_RUNTIME python27
CURRENT_VERSION_ID 1.790710791652471334
USER_ID 
USER_ORGANIZATION 
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH 0
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
HTTP_HOST localhost:8080
CURRENT_MODULE_ID default
TZ UTC
HTTP_COOKIE _ga=GA1.1.2122305447.1428161397; connect.sid=s%3AWErSIaaWXlGMkYqcwwBrikSFU1Xy4EGS.xOv8DCRhhTx2xaKiK4wRJsQh3ol9pG3njPxPexQiRdA
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL no-cache
AUTH_DOMAIN gmail.com
USER_IS_ADMIN 0
wsgi.input <cStringIO.StringI object at 0x7fd47f92c0b8>
REQUEST_ID_HASH 9B7C4FEB
SERVER_PORT 8080
```

Some are dependant of where or how they are run, e.g. the HTTP_USER_AGENT or REQUEST_METHOD may vary.

[You may also define your own environmental variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables) if you would rather use those:

> You can define variables in app.yaml to make them available to the
>   program's os.environ dictionary:
>
> ```
> env_variables:
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myapp.settings'
> ```

Comment: You can also check which version and/or module you are running.